# Limiting 7zip CPU usage on Windows Server 2008 (from batch file)

Tags: windows-server-2008, compression

Does anyone know of a way (specific to 7zip or general) to limit the CPU usage of 7zip while it is archiving a long list of files? OS is Windows Server 2008 R2, and 7zip is run via command line from a batch file.

Answer (score 11):

Don't worry about the actual CPU percentage, instead you should start the process using a different priority.  So from the command line you should be able to use `start /low command` to start a command that only runs the system is IDLE.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in powershell you can do something like this:

```
$start = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$start.Arguments = "--argument1 --argument2"
$start.FileName = "C:\bin\7zip.exe"
$proc = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$proc.PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::BelowNormal
$proc.StartInfo = $start
$proc.Start().WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not currently using powershell, but am thinking of updating the old batch files to it.

Comment: I tried this with ffmpeg it did not work got an error. Error:**Exception setting "PriorityClass": "No process is associated with this object."
+ $proc. <<<< PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::BelowNormal
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
 
Method invocation failed because [System.Boolean] doesn't contain a method named 'WaitForExit'.** Had to chop the error short because of character limit but that's the general idea.

Answer (score -2):

I am using [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533.aspx) on all servers. When I just want to limit a one time execution of a process, I can choose the priority through the context menu of the process 7z.exe - see attached image.
[Set priority to Idle in context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpgpJ.jpg)

Comment: Another answer (from nearly 5 years ago) already suggests starting a process with lower priority.

Comment: The nice thing about process explorer is that you don't have to stop and restart the process - you can reduce the priority at any time, even when the process was already running for an hour and you now realize that it's draining to much of the CPU.